# Google is not defined using react google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I have read the other questions related to this and tried implementing what the answers were on there.

They recommended adding `/*global google */` - did not work

Next was to add `const google = window.google;` - did not work

I will post the code below and the error.

The error is happening where `new google.maps` is being called

Map.js:

```
/* global google */
import { default as React, Component } from 'react';
import raf from 'raf';
import canUseDOM from 'can-use-dom';

const google = window.google;

import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Circle, InfoWindow, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';
import withScriptjs from 'react-google-maps/lib/async/withScriptjs';

const googleMapURL =
  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.27&libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyA7XEFRxE4Lm28tAh44M_568fCLOP_On3k';
const geolocation =
  canUseDOM && navigator.geolocation
    ? navigator.geolocation
    : {
      getCurrentPosition(success, failure) {
        failure("Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
      },
    };
const GeolocationExampleGoogleMap = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props =>
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} center={props.center}>
      {props.center &&
        <InfoWindow position={props.center}>
          <div>User's Location</div>
        </InfoWindow>}
      {props.center &&
        <Circle
          center={props.center}
          radius={props.radius}
          options={{
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeColor: 'red',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 1,
          }}
        />}
      >
      {props.markers.map((marker, index) => {
        const onClick = () => props.onMarkerClick(marker);
        const onCloseClick = () => props.onCloseClick(marker);

        return (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            position={marker.position}
            title={(index + 1).toString()}
            onClick={onClick}
          >
            {marker.showInfo &&
              <InfoWindow onCloseClick={onCloseClick}>
                <div>
                  <strong>
                    {marker.content}
                  </strong>
                  <br />
                  <em>The contents of this InfoWindow are actually ReactElements.</em>
                </div>
              </InfoWindow>}
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </GoogleMap>,
  ),
);

function generateInitialMarkers() {
  const southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.203405, 125.244141);
  const northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

  const lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  const latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

  const markers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const position = new google.maps.LatLng(
      southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
      southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random(),
    );
    markers.push({
      position,
      content: 'This is the secret message'.split(' ')[i],
      showInfo: false,
    });
  }
  return markers;
}

export default class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      center: null,
      content: null,
      radius: 6000,
      markers: generateInitialMarkers(),
    };

    const isUnmounted = false;
    handleMarkerClick = this.handleMarkerClick.bind(this);
    handleCloseClick = this.handleCloseClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleMarkerClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
      markers: this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
        if (marker === targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: true,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),
    });
  }

  handleCloseClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
      markers: this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
        if (marker === targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: false,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const tick = () => {
      if (this.isUnmounted) {
        return;
      }
      this.setState({ radius: Math.max(this.state.radius - 20, 0) });

      if (this.state.radius > 200) {
        raf(tick);
      }
    };

    geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        if (this.isUnmounted) {
          return;
        }
        this.setState({
          center: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          },
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.',
        });

        raf(tick);
      },
      (reason) => {
        if (this.isUnmounted) {
          return;
        }

        this.setState({
          center: {
            lat: 60,
            lng: 105,
          },
          content: `Error: The Geolocation service failed (${reason}).`,
        });
      },
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isUnmounted = true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GeolocationExampleGoogleMap
        googleMapURL={googleMapURL}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }}>loading...</div>}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
        center={this.state.center}
        content={this.state.content}
        radius={this.state.radius}
        onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
        onCloseClick={this.handleCloseClick}
        markers={this.state.markers}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you added the `<script>` to your `index.html` file?

Comment: Forget it I saw `withScript` in your code

Comment: I shouldn't have to since I am using the withScriptjs wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading async script. When you initialize google constant there is no google object. You can solve this by using 'ref' for map component. Ref callback fired when google object exists. For example:

```
<GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} center={props.center} ref={()=>{props.onMapLoad}}>...</GoogleMap>
...
constructor(props) {
   ...
   this.onMapLoad = this.onMapLoad.bind(this)
}
...
onMapLoad() {
  /*init markers and all objects with "google" here*/
}
...   
<GeolocationExampleGoogleMap
    onMapLoad={this.onMapLoad}
    ...
    />
```

and, of course, do not init google const, use just google object instead,

Comment: What would I set the marker state to? I moved that function into the `onMapLoad()`

Comment: Thank you! I will be adding my own logic in here anyway so I guess this question was really just for others.